# How to keep attachments in temporary file, not in memory, during web service message download on JBoss

Tags: web-services, jboss, jbossws

I have the following problem on JBoss 4.2.3 and 5.1 using JBoss WS Native Stack. The web service is receiving a significant number of large attachments. When my server is receiving these attachments, they are stored in memory until the whole message is transfered and parsed.

As a result, I am runnig out of memory quickly (due to large number of clients).

I would prefer JBossWS was storing attachements in some temporary file, not in memory.

Is there any option in JBoss that sets the threshold above which the attachment is kept in file, not in RAM? Axis 2 has such option (see the last chapter of http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_1_1/mtom-guide.html), but I couldn't find anything similar in JBossWS. Is there such an option for Apache CXF or Metro web services implementation for JBoss?